# Grails application root path

Tags: grails, jetty

Is there a variable where I can find out the root directory of my Grails application?

for example, I have a folder named `chart` under `\%root%\web-app\images\` where I put my charts in. Once I deploy my Grails application on Jetty, I will get `FileNotFoundException` because the root path becomes `/srv/www/vhosts/domain-name/jetty-version/`

I would like to know if there is a variable that returns the root path (like `/srv/www/vhosts/domain-name/jetty-version/webapps/myapp`), and there should be because CSS uses relative path just fine.

Comment: I guess my question is: why do you need to get to the root path?  You can use the relative URL /images/charts to get to your charts as well so getting the root path seems like extra work in this case.

Comment: I used relative URL but it could not find the folder. 
new File("..").getAbsolutePath() yields the same result as System.properties['base.dir'] 
Both returns the root folder of the Jetty folder instead of my application folder.

Comment: @steve.yu, please mark Martijn's as correct answer while it's working and quite simple.

Answer (score 15):

solved.

```
request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
```

this actually gives me the path to where my application puts the images, css, WEB-INF, etc. folders.

Answer (score 11):

```
System.properties['base.dir']
```

Comment: In grails2.1 this works in local dev mode but doesn't appear to work in production

Comment: And in grails 3+ this is `null`

Answer (score 9):

I know it is an old question, but this could work if you are not in an http request:

```
ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getRealPath('/')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please click the "?" by the text box next time you post an answer to see how to format posts.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to establish this is GSPs try this:

```
${createLink(uri: '/')}
```

Comment: Or you can use this too ${request.contextPath}

Comment: downvote because the question was abouth path and not URL

Comment: Upvote because the title of the question led me straight from DuckDuckGo to an answer I was looking for. "This answer is useful", yes!